# WPF Listview bound with Hashtable

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

I already bind a listview (grid) with hashtable, so how can I get items from there? Before using hashtable I just did `ListViewA.SelectedItems;` and I was getting the source.

Ir fails when I use two `foreach` loops:

`dlstTemplates` is my ListView in WPF

```
foreach (var group in dlstTemplates.SelectedItems)
{
  foreach (var Template in group)
  {

  }
}
```

> Error 2   foreach statement cannot
>   operate on variables of type 'object'
>   because 'object' does not contain a
>   public definition for
>   'GetEnumerator'   D:\cs_InformeMedico\app\Template.xaml.cs    85  21  Demo.View

I found this on debugger:

```
-       dlstPlantillas.SelectedItems    Count = 1   System.Collections.IList {System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection}
-       [0] {System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Group<string,Demo.View.Plantilla>} object {System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Group<string,Demo.View.Plantilla>}
-       Non-Public members      
+       items   Count = 97  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Demo.View.Plantilla> {System.Collections.Generic.List<Demo.View.Plantilla>}
        key "101010112000"  string
        System.Linq.IGrouping<K,T>.Key  "101010112000"  string
-       Results View    Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable   
+       [0] {Demo.View.Plantilla}   Demo.View.Plantilla
+       [1] {Demo.View.Plantilla}   Demo.View.Plantilla
+       [2] {Demo.View.Plantilla}   Demo.View.Plantilla
+       [3] {Demo.View.Plantilla}   Demo.View.Plantilla
+       [4] {Demo.View.Plantilla}   Demo.View.Plantilla
+       [5] {Demo.View.Plantilla}   Demo.View.Plantilla
+       [6] {Demo.View.Plantilla}   Demo.View.Plantilla
+       [7] {Demo.View.Plantilla}   Demo.View.Plantilla
+       [8] {Demo.View.Plantilla}   Demo.View.Plantilla
+       [9] {Demo.View.Plantilla}   Demo.View.Plantilla
+       [10]    {Demo.View.Plantilla}   Demo.View.Plantilla
-       Raw View        
-       [System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection]    Count = 1   System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection
+       [0] {System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Group<string,Demo.View.Plantilla>} object {System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Group<string,Demo.View.Plantilla>}
+       Raw View        
        IsFixedSize false   bool
        IsReadOnly  false   bool
```

So when group is a

```
{System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Group<string,Demo.View.Plantilla>} object type
```

Sorry Plantilla = Template, I traduce it for more understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be working with a collection in the second loop.
Maybe you wanted

```
foreach(var group in dlstTemplates.SelectedItems)
{
    foreach(var Template in groupCast.Templates)
    {
        //do stuff...
    }
}
```

or somesuch.

Comment: I cant get Templates as property in groupCast, so I Have to add a Default property in my Template Class named Templates?

Comment: when I try that I get Error 1 'Template': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type D:\cs_InformeMedico\app\Template.cs 26 26 Demo.View

Comment: No.  You were trying to enumerate a single object in the 2nd loop.  You use foreach you must work on a collection.  foreach(var thing in (int)17) will yield the same error you were getting.

Comment: Perhaps if you posted the code for your collection member in dlstTemplates.SelectedItems) we could sort this out

Answer (score 0):

```
            foreach (var group in dlstPlantillas.SelectedItems)
            {
                IGrouping<string, Plantilla> groupCast = group as System.Linq.IGrouping<string, Plantilla>;
                if (null == groupCast) return;
                foreach (Plantilla item in groupCast)
                {
                    template.codigoestudio = item.codigoestudio;

                }
            }
```

hopes helps... thanks ZombieSheep for inspiration!